# SQL Server : prevent output of tablename with date later then today

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to display data with 11 months from 11 tables. Each table containing a different months data. The table name contains the date of each table. At the moment my code works in a way that a person has to input a date such as 201404 then it will display all months from 201404 right up to 201503. I need to put a check in place so that if the person types in 201507 it only throws out 201507 up to 201510 as the remaining months do not exists as yet.

This is my code:

```
alter PROCEDURE stp3
     @FirstTableMonth int =0,
        @EndMonth datetime
AS

DECLARE 
            @LinkedServerName sysname = 'SERVER1',
            @left int = 0,
            @right int= 0,
            @STRING VARCHAR(6),
            @monthex int = 12,
            @yearex int,
            @yearstring int,
            @DynamicSQL nvarchar(max) = '',
            @DynamicSQL2 nvarchar(max) = '',
            @OpenQuerySql nvarchar(max),
            @Table_Name sysname,
            @Table_Name2 sysname,
            @TableMonth int,
            @TableMonth2 int ,
            @CurrentMonth int = 0,
            @NextYearMonth int = 1,
            @part2 nvarchar(max) = '',
            @TwelfthMonth int = 0;


        SET @FirstTableMonth= CAST(@FirstTableMonth AS VARCHAR(6))
        set @left = cast(left(@FirstTableMonth,4) +1   as varchar(max))
        set @right = right(@FirstTableMonth,2) - 1 
        set @monthex = 11
        set @yearex = cast(left(@FirstTableMonth,4)   as varchar(max))
        set @yearstring = case when right(@FirstTableMonth,2) = '01' then left(@FirstTableMonth,4)  + RIGHT( @monthex + LTRIM( RTRIM( right(@FirstTableMonth,2) ) ), 6 ) else @left end 
        SET @STRING  = 
            case when  right(@FirstTableMonth,2) = '01' then @yearstring
            when @right < 10 then CAST(@left AS VARCHAR(4)) + RIGHT( '0' + LTRIM( RTRIM( @right ) ), 6 ) 
            else CAST(@left AS VARCHAR(4)) + RIGHT(  LTRIM( RTRIM( @right ) ), 6 ) end 


WHILE @CurrentMonth < 11 AND @EndMonth < getdate()
BEGIN

    SELECT  @TableMonth =   CASE WHEN (@FirstTableMonth + @CurrentMonth) % 100 < 13 THEN 
                                @FirstTableMonth + @CurrentMonth 
                            ELSE
                                @FirstTableMonth + 100 - (@FirstTableMonth % 100) + @NextYearMonth
                            END,
                    @NextYearMonth =    CASE WHEN (@FirstTableMonth + @CurrentMonth) % 100 < 13 THEN 
                                    @NextYearMonth
                                ELSE
                                    @NextYearMonth + 1
                                END,
                    @Table_Name =  'XX_'+CAST(@TableMonth as varchar)+'_T' ,

                    @TableMonth2 = @TableMonth,
                    @Table_Name2 = 'XX_'+CAST(@TableMonth2 as varchar)+'_T'  ,


            @DynamicSQL = @DynamicSQL + 
                                    'SELECT 
                                            *
                                         FROM '+ @Table_Name + ' 
'+ CASE WHEN @CurrentMonth < 10 THEN ' UNION ALL ' ELSE '' END ,


                  @DynamicSQL2 = @DynamicSQL2 + 
                                'SELECT 
                                        *
                                     FROM '+ @Table_Name2 + ' 
' 


        SET @CurrentMonth = @CurrentMonth + 1
        IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TEMP')       IS NOT NULL BEGIN DROP TABLE #TEMP END
        IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Unioned')        IS NOT NULL BEGIN DROP TABLE #Unioned END
--last months snapshot
    SELECT 
                        *
                INTO #UNIONED
            FROM OPENQUERY(SERVER1,' SELECT 
                        *
            FROM yy_T  
'
                                                            )
            union all
            SELECT 
                        *
            FROM OPENQUERY(SERVER1,' SELECT 
                        *
            FROM yk  
'
                                                                                                    )                                                                               
DECLARE @dateAsNumber VARCHAR(8);
SET @dateAsNumber = CONVERT(CHAR(6),GETDATE(), 112);
DECLARE @DateConvertedFromNumber DATETIME; 
SELECT  @DateConvertedFromNumber = CONVERT (DATETIME, CONVERT(CHAR(8), @dateAsNumber + '01'))

                select 
                            *
                            LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,   DATEADD(MONTH, -1,@DateConvertedFromNumber), 112),6) AS 'Period'
                            INTO #temp
                from #Unioned


    drop table OpenQTable


--if equal to month + 99 = previous month then union 11 tables with last months snapshot 
--else 
--union 11 tables with 12th table
SET @OpenQuerySql = 'IF  (' + cast(@FirstTableMonth as varchar) + '+99) = CONVERT(nvarchar(6), dateadd(month,-1,GETDATE()), 112)
    BEGIN
                    SELECT *
            FROM OPENQUERY(['+ @LinkedServerName +'], '''+ @DynamicSQL + ''' ) 
    UNION ALL 
                SELECT *
    FROM #temp
    END
    else 
    begin 
                SELECT *
                FROM OPENQUERY(['+ @LinkedServerName +'], '''+ @DynamicSQL + ''' ) 
    UNION ALL 
                SELECT *
                FROM OPENQUERY(['+ @LinkedServerName +'], '''+ @DynamicSQL2 + ''' ) 
    end
'
END

insert into  OpenQTable
EXECUTE sp_executesql @OpenQuerySql 

go
```

}

Comment: Tag dbms used. This doesn't look like ANSI SQL at all...

Comment: Whatever you do, just stop. Use date functions like `DATEADD/DATEDIFF/DATEPART/DATEFROMPARTS` and so on instead of manipulating string. When your code will be deployed on server with different locale, all will fail like house of cards.

Comment: OK Will do. but now how do I do my check to see that no date later then today is entered? I can use a @enddate parameter but not sure what the logic around it is

Comment: could someone please inform Zohar Peled about this link as he helped me with the code. I cant not seem to access chat.

Comment: Spreading data across named tables like this is a design flaw. If you had all the data in one table with a month field you wouldn't have a problem. If you have the opportunity, spend your time fixing this design issue rather than working around it like this.

Comment: Excuse me. I was not the one who designed the structure of the database!

Comment: Sorry didn't mean to point the finger. I figured that might be the case. So this is an example of "technical debt" where you spend all your time working around issues rather than fixing them. and I know that fixing a DB design is a big deal and I know that there are very few jobs where you get to build the DB correct from the start. Good luck anyway.

Comment: Please can you refer Zohar Peled to this chat as my reputation score is low in order to perform a chat